# MYSQL Getting Main Categories

Tags: mysql, relationships

I have the following query that lists categories and the parent category to which are related to.

```
t.term_id is the category ID
tx.parent is the ID of category from which they depend from. 
Main Categories have parent id= 0
```

And this is the problem since the query is not displaying main categories but only sub-category. Basically it is showing only records where parent>0 but I need parent =>0. I already put it in the where condition but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT t.term_id, t.name, tx.parent, tm.name
from mg_terms t

join mg_term_taxonomy tx
on tx.term_id = t.term_id

join mg_terms tm
on tm.term_id = tx.parent

where tx.taxonomy='product_cat'  
ORDER BY `tx`.`parent`  DESC
```

Any help to get main categories (parent=0) as well?

Comment: Mmm, If I understood you correctly, all you need is `LEFT JOIN mg_terms tm` instead of `JOIN mg_terms tm`

Comment: Oh most likely. I  come up soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either make use of UNION select and join the two results:

```
SELECT t.term_id, t.name, tx.parent, tm.name
FROM mg_terms t
JOIN mg_term_taxonomy tx ON tx.term_id = t.term_id
JOIN mg_terms tm ON tm.term_id = tx.parent
WHERE tx.taxonomy='product_cat'  
UNION 
SELECT t2.term_id, t2.name, tx2.parent, null
FROM mg_terms t2
JOIN mg_term_taxonomy tx2 ON tx2.term_id = t2.term_id
WHERE tx2.taxonomy='product_cat' AND t2.parent = 0
ORDER BY parent
```

or SELECT all from mg_terms t and LEFT JOIN mg_terms tm, as also suggested by sagi.

```
SELECT t.term_id, t.name, tx.parent, tm.name
FROM mg_terms t
JOIN mg_term_taxonomy tx ON tx.term_id = t.term_id
LEFT JOIN mg_terms tm ON tm.term_id = tx.parent
WHERE tx.taxonomy='product_cat'  
ORDER BY `tx`.`parent`
```

Comment: Confirmed, it needed of LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN only. Thanks Roman.